# Decorate an imported class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, overriding, python-decorators

This is what I'm trying to do:

import a class.
override/decorate the implementation of one of its methods.
pass this class name to a function and that function will do something.

Typically, if I pass an instance of a class, it is very easy to control the behavior of this instance's methods after I pass it into a function. This is because before I pass it into the function, I can set/initiate the instance member value correctly and they can control the behavior of that instance.

However, this function takes a class name and use this class to create instances inside that function. I cannot change this function because it lives in other people's library.

Here is what I tried:

My first script:

```
class Target:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Target initiated")

    def getFlag(self):
        return("True")
```

My second script:

```
from firstScript import Target

def main():
    def decorator_function(target):
        def decoratorFlag(self):
            return(False)
        target.getFlag = decoratorFlag
        return(target)

    local_class = Target
    obj=local_class()
    print(obj.getFlag())

    local_class = decorator_function(Target)
    obj=local_class()
    print(obj.getFlag())

    obj=Target()
    print(obj.getFlag())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After I do this. The first time when I run the second script, I have the output:

```
Target initiated
True
Target initiated
False
Target initiated
False
```

But the second time when I run this script, I have these

```
Target initiated
False
Target initiated
False
Target initiated
False
```

Could anyone help me understand why the behavior is different? I have been searching for topics about decoration but most of the answer requires the class be defined in the same script. I cannot find the solution for a class imported from another script.

Comment: I assume this has something to do with reference assignment, but I am not sure. Could inheritance work for you? __getattr__ is a powerful feature.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get `True/False/False` every time. I'm not sure how any sort of state could be carried over from one run to the next to change the output.

Comment: You don't need decorator just inherit the class and override the function whose behaviour needs to be changed

Comment: I think if I restart the shell, the behavior is consistent. Otherwise the second time when I run it in the same shell the result will be false false and false

Comment: Let me explain why I don't inherit. I didn't explain this in my original code snippet. In fact, I'm trying to pass a derived class name here. That class inherits the default class and override 3 methods. It is defined in a separate script.

Comment: Then I have another issue, in some cases I still want to use the method in the base class, which means I need to use super().methodName(). This is case by case, sometimes I want to use the base class method 1, sometime I want to use the base class 2 and etc.

Comment: It should be very easy if I introduce some new member value/method as flags in the derived class and make their value correct when I initiate an instance. However, like I said I need to pass a class name instead of an instance. If I don't have instance, I cannot config member values as flags. So that is why I want to import the class, use some tricks to change its definition and pass its name to the next function.

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing the original class instead of modifying it?

```
class ImportedClass:
    def someMethod():
        pass

class Subclass(ImportedClass):
    @decorator
    def someMethod():
        super().someMethod()
```